# CMake: "No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found" error when building project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, compilation, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to compile a C++ project in Windows 10, consisting of the following files:

- src/setup.cpp
- src/setup.h
- CMakeLists.txt

setup.cpp is as follows:

```
#include "setup.h"

int myFunction() {
    return 42;
}
```

setup.h is as follows:

```
#ifndef SETUP_DLL
#define SETUP_DLL

int myFunction();

#endif
```

CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyLibrary VERSION 1.0.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
add_library(MyLibrary SHARED src/setup.h src/setup.cpp)
target_include_directories(MyLibrary PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set_target_properties(MyLibrary PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "MyLibrary_${PROJECT_VERSION}")
set_target_properties(MyLibrary PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")
```

I'm trying to compile the project using the following commands using the Windows 10's "Command Prompt":

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"
cmake --build .
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Microsoft (R) Build Engine versione 16.11.2+f32259642 per .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti sono riservati.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: il file di progetto non esiste.
Opzione: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

### **UPDATE**

This is the components that I have installed in Visual Studio 2019

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the desktop development components in Visual Studio installer?

Comment: Are you building from a developer command prompt, or just from the regular command prompt? It should be the former.

Comment: I'm executing the building script via command prompt (cmd).

Comment: @El_Merendero That is incorrect. Use 'StartMenu/Visual Studio 2019/Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019'. The regular command prompt does not have the correct environment setup for CMake to be able to discover the compiler.

Comment: I just tried to use the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" (using Administrator privilegies) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is that the complete output? Cmake must show you where the error log file is located. Take a look at the error log file content.

Comment: Yes, that is the full output

Comment: All should work well. Something is not done properly. Have you finished VS installation and rebooted the PC?

Comment: Yes but I installed VS2019 in a custom folder. Could be this the problem?

Comment: No, it must not be a problem, cmake looks for VS installation path in Windows registry.

Comment: when you say "it doesn't work", what exactly are you saying doesn't work? Did you restart from the configure command? Or did you try to use the existing generated buildsystem? Because you need to restart from the configure command inside the VS Dev Prompt.

Comment: @user I mean I tried to start "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" (both as administrator and normal user) and tried to re-run the above mentioned commands. However the instruction `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"` generates the same error. I also tried restarting the PC but nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: could it be a variable caching thing? (CMake has a variable cache for cached variables) what if you delete the build folder first before rerunning the configure command?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is another test I tried. Unfortunately, even deleting the build folder, the error remains the same.

Comment: MSVC does not support C++  11 standard. Will the problem be solved if changing to 14?